# Sublime Text Plugin - How do I get the start point of a particular line?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm experimenting creating a plugin for sublime text (3) after looking at a few [references](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and [tutorials](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685).

As a simple exercise I thought I'd create a vbscript commenting plugin - it should insert an apostrophe at the beginning of each line of selected text.

So far I've managed iterate selected regions and split them into separate lines. But I'm having trouble finding the start point of each line.  (Called `lineStart` in my code below).

I think that  variable is needed to find the exact point at which to insert the apostrophe. How do I get that?

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AspCommentCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):

        for selectedRegion in self.view.sel():
            selection = self.view.substr(selectedRegion)
            for line in selection.split('\n'):
                lineStart = ?????
                self.view.insert(edit, lineStart, "'")
```

**Update**

Hooray. I have managed to iterate the selected lines, and insert an apostrophe at the beginning of each one, using this code:

```
class AspAddCommentCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):

        for selectedRegion in self.view.sel():
            selectedLines = self.view.lines(selectedRegion)
            adjustBy = 0
            for line in selectedLines:
                 insertPoint = line.begin() + adjustBy
                 self.view.insert(edit, insertPoint, "'")
                 adjustBy += 1
```

But after inserting an apostrophe on the first line, I then need to adjust the insert point of the next line to allow for the extra apostrophe character.

Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: If you're making a plugin for ST3 you probably want [this API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) and [this reference of missing objects](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html) instead of the one linked in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I have to say that I find the docs a bit impenetrable... but at least now I'll be looking at the right version, which is a step in the right direction

Comment: Will it work if you iterate over the lines in reverse order?

Comment: Yeah it does, I just wondered if there was a slicker approach to take, it seems kind of hacky to have to do that

Answer (score 1):

In a Sublime Text 3 plugin, you can get the start of a known line using

```
self.view.text_point(line - 1, 0)
```

In the documentation, they refer to `row` not line. Row means zero-based line number.

Comment: Wow, this question takes me back a few years! Thanks